# How to increment a number with the form x.y.z

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with trying to increment the farthest right number in the form of `x.y.z` without the use of indexing. I've never worked with a float before that had more than 1 decimal point and don't know how to get this started. I think I would need to convert each individual value into an integer and then use a string to output them.

The final product needs to look something like this:

```
1.7.9 => 1.7.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a hard time doing this with floats (you can't have 2 decimal places in a float)... I'd suggest you track the `x.y.z` separately as integers and then you can increment them individually:

```
x = 1
y = 7
z = 9

print(f"{x}.{y}.{z}")
# "1.7.9"

z += 1

print(f"{x}.{y}.{z}")
# "1.7.10"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "float with more than 1 decimal point". Floats are real numbers. What you are looking for can be accomplished with something like that:

```python
>>> version = "1.7.9"
>>> parts = version.split(".")
>>> parts
['1', '7', '9']
>>> parts[2] = str(int(parts[2]) + 1)
>>> parts
['1', '7', '10']
>>> ".".join(parts)
'1.7.10'
```

Comment: You could use `distutils.version.StrictVersion` or `distutils.version.LooseVersion`  to avoid rewriting the wheel.

Comment: @flakes I didn't know about those classes, thanks, but it looks like `distutils` is being deprecated. Oh well...

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realize the deprecation. I wonder if bumpversion exports any methods publicly?

Comment: I use [setuptools_scm](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) often. It works well with git repos and my normal Python build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an object to store x, y and z :

```
class xyz:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}.{self.y}.{self.z}"

    def __iadd__(self, value):
        self.z += value
        return self

obj = xyz(1, 7, 9)

print(obj) # 1.7.9

obj += 1

print(obj) # 1.7.10
```

Comment: Hint: You could've also overridden `__iadd__`. You can then simply write `obj += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you can not have two decimal places in a `float`, and the easiest way to solve your problem is just using indexing of `str`.

```
s = "1.7.9"
print(''.join(s[:-1]+str(int(s[-1])+1)))
```

But since you don't want to use indexing you can use the following code instead. But using this code is like you are using a hammer to squash a fly. So it is not recommended and this is only because you asked for a way to do it. And remember even inside those functions they use indexing to give the output.

```
s = "1.7.9"
t = '.'.join([str(int(x)+1 if x in s.rpartition(".") else int(x)) for x in s.split(".")])
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out;

```
a = '1.7.9'
output = a[:-1]+ str(int(a.split('.')[-1])+1)
print(output) # 1.7.10
```